# How to pass a InternalFrameFocusTraversalPolicy variable to an inner class?

Tags: java, swing

I defined the polity like code below.

```
public class Cruzada extends JInternalFrame implements changeFocusListener
{   
    Cell cell[][]; // Array of JTextFields
    private FocusTraversalPolicy politicaV;

    politicaV = new InternalFrameFocusTraversalPolicy();

    for(int c = 0; c < colunas; c++){
        for(int l = 0; l < linhas; l++){
            ((InternalFrameFocusTraversalPolicy)politicaV).addIndexedComponent(cell[c-(c-l)][l+(c-l)]);
        }
```

And in the inner class I call the method setFocusTraversalPolicy(politicaV), but i'ts not working.

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say with so little code provided but you could try making the politicaV a final variable like this:

```
private final FocusTraversalPolicy politicaV = new InternalFrameFocusTraversalPolicy();
```

If the inner class is static, you'll need to make the variable static too.

If this doesn't work, you should provide the error stack trace and more code, it's impossible to help otherwise.